# How to store value of a FQL in variable

Tags: php, facebook-fql

Am trying to extract user information from user.
Am able to get that using fql. but the main problem is that i am not able to store a particular data,say name, in a separate variable
I want to show that value in a textbox in my webpage.
Can anybidy tell me that what's wrong?

```
<?php
$app_id = '237773783026***';
$app_secret = '90a6514ebed8***f47a3d9a695608315';
$my_url = 'http://apps.facebook.com/anubhawfirst';

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

// auth user
if(empty($code)) {
$dialog_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=' 
$app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) ;
echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
}

// get user access_token
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
$app_id . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($my_url) 
. '&client_secret=' . $app_secret 
. '&code=' . $code;

// response is of the format "access_token=AAAC..."
$access_token = substr(file_get_contents($token_url), 13);

// run fql query
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. 'fql?q=SELECT+name+,+uid+FROM+user+WHERE+uid=me()'
. '&access_token=' . $access_token;
$fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
$fql_query_obj = array(json_decode($fql_query_result, true));

//this is the part where am trying to extract using array.
foreach ($fql_query_obj as $item)
{ 

print $fql_query_obj[0];
;
}

// display results of fql query

echo '<pre>';
print_r("query results:");
print_r($fql_query_obj);
echo '</pre>';


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a multidimensional array containing the results of your query.  The values in the uid and name columns are four levels deep.  Access them like this:

```
$uid = $fql_query_obj[0]['data'][0]['uid'];
$name = $fql_query_obj[0]['data'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I added,
$uid = $fql_query_obj[0]['data'][0]['uid'];
echo($uid); 
before the last 4 lines of print statement but nothing is happening. I mean it aint showing anything.
Btw i didnt explicitly the size of array. So how come it's 4 level dep? 
Am really new to fql. :)